# OCI runtime exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "no such file or directory": unknown

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm running sample tutorial from [Hyperledger Fabric Doc](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4.html), trying to run the "Build Your First Network" sample with following command `./byfn.sh`.

- Network generation works fine, but when I try to up the network:

  ```
  $ cd..../fabric-samples/first-network
  $ ./byfn.sh generate
  $ ./byfn.sh up
  ```
- I receive the following error:

  ```
    Starting for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and 
    CLI delay of '3' seconds
    Continue? [Y/n] y
    proceeding ...
    LOCAL_VERSION=1.4.1
    DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.4.1
    Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
    Creating peer1.org2.example.com ... done
    Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... done
    Creating orderer.example.com    ... done
    Creating peer1.org1.example.com ... done
    Creating cli                    ... done

    **OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting 
    container process caused "no such file or directory": unknown
    ERROR !!!! Test failed**
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalled docker, deleted previous node modules, re-run the network, finally worked fine.

```
$./byfn.sh down
$docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
$docker volume prune
$./byfn.sh generate
$./byfn.sh up
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I changed back to a working docker project, everything worked well, that is why I doubt that reinstalling docker is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you take the workaround using sh:

> Using the docker command `docker exec -it <your container> sh` will
> allow you to overcome the issue. It does appear that bash is not
> installed in the container.

Source: [OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/963#issuecomment-728085455)

Comment: Yep now this source might be useful and correct, but back then 2019 year there was no any reliable source :)

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov All good. You could set it up again and the error was gone. In my case, setting it up again might still have thrown the same error since the path env var for bash would not be set in the container. Yours and mine are then two different answers, and mine might rather not have helped you, but might help others with the same error.

Comment: You are right, it will definitely help for those who face same problem. But I think now there might be much more issues as the Fabric version also changed a lot.